# How to get the day of the week from a date and insert the time into another dataset in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Here dataset, where is the store opening hours by day of the week

```
store=structure(list(weekday_code = c("fri", "mon", "sat", "sun", "thu", 
"tue", "wen"), workday_sign = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    opening_time = c("9:00:00", "9:00:00", "9:00:00", "10:00:00", 
    "9:00:00", "9:00:00", "9:00:00"), closing_time = c("18:00:00", 
    "18:00:00", "17:00:00", "16:00:00", "18:00:00", "18:00:00", 
    "18:00:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```

the second dataset also has opening_time and closing_time columns (dt_start and dt_end).

```
wrong=structure(list(kod_dolg = c(50000690L, 801L, 50000690L, 801L, 
50000690L, 801L, 801L, 50000690L, 801L, 50000690L, 50000690L, 
801L, 50000690L, 50000690L, 50000690L, 801L, 50000690L, 801L, 
50000690L, 801L, 50000690L, 801L, 50000690L, 50000690L, 801L, 
801L, 50000690L, 50000690L, 50000690L, 801L, 50000690L, 50000690L, 
50000690L, 801L, 50000690L, 801L, 50000690L), dt_start = c("14.02.2022 12:00", 
"14.02.2022 11:00", "14.02.2022 10:00", "15.02.2022 8:00", "15.02.2022 8:00", 
"15.02.2022 10:00", "15.02.2022 12:00", "15.02.2022 12:00", "16.02.2022 11:00", 
"16.02.2022 12:00", "16.02.2022 13:00", "17.02.2022 10:00", "17.02.2022 10:00", 
"17.02.2022 12:00", "17.02.2022 13:00", "18.02.2022 8:00", "18.02.2022 8:00", 
"18.02.2022 10:00", "18.02.2022 10:00", "18.02.2022 12:00", "18.02.2022 12:00", 
"12.02.2022 10:00", "12.02.2022 13:00", "12.02.2022 12:00", "12.02.2022 12:00", 
"19.02.2022 10:00", "19.02.2022 13:00", "19.02.2022 12:00", "19.02.2022 12:00", 
"20.02.2022 10:00", "20.02.2022 10:00", "20.02.2022 12:00", "20.02.2022 13:00", 
"13.02.2022 10:00", "13.02.2022 10:00", "13.02.2022 12:00", "13.02.2022 12:00"
), dt_end = c("14.02.2022 22:00", "14.02.2022 21:00", "14.02.2022 20:00", 
"15.02.2022 10:00", "15.02.2022 10:00", "15.02.2022 20:00", "15.02.2022 22:00", 
"15.02.2022 22:00", "16.02.2022 21:00", "16.02.2022 22:00", "16.02.2022 20:00", 
"17.02.2022 20:00", "17.02.2022 20:00", "17.02.2022 22:00", "17.02.2022 22:00", 
"18.02.2022 10:00", "18.02.2022 10:00", "18.02.2022 20:00", "18.02.2022 20:00", 
"18.02.2022 22:00", "18.02.2022 22:00", "12.02.2022 20:00", "12.02.2022 20:00", 
"12.02.2022 22:00", "12.02.2022 22:00", "19.02.2022 20:00", "19.02.2022 20:00", 
"19.02.2022 22:00", "19.02.2022 22:00", "20.02.2022 20:00", "20.02.2022 20:00", 
"20.02.2022 22:00", "20.02.2022 22:00", "13.02.2022 20:00", "13.02.2022 20:00", 
"13.02.2022 22:00", "13.02.2022 22:00"), person_number = c(976291L, 
754105L, 867801L, NA, 867801L, NA, NA, 867801L, NA, 976291L, 
938541L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-37L))
```

In first dataset `store` there is column `weekday_code`

```
fri Friday
mon Monday
sat saturday
sun Sunday
thu Thursday
tue Tuesday
wen wednesday
```

but in second dataset `wrong` there is not  column `weekday_code`.
So the question how from dates from `dt_start` and `dt_end` get weekday? For example `14.02.2022 10:00` is monday.
Then the second queustion is how to insert work hours on specific days of the week into `wrong` dataset from  `store` dataset.
Example.In `wrong` dataset monday dt_start=14.02.2022 12:00 and dt_end=14.02.2022  22:00:00
but in store dataset in  monday this shop must work from 9-18.
So for each monday date in `wrong` dataset i must change work hours like that
dt_start=14.02.2022 9:00:00 and dt_end=14.02.2022  18:00:00.

Similarly for other days of the week. In other words, i find the date in the `wrong`, determine its day of the week, look at the open and closing hours for this day of the week in `store` and insert these hours into the dt_start and dt_end that corresponds to this day of the week.

How can i make such permutations of working hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing you'll have to do is, change the data type of `dt_start` and `dt_end` to `POXIXct`.
Then you need to create different columns for storing date and time.

Here's how you'll do it:

```
wrong$dt_start <- as.POSIXct(wrong$dt_start, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M", tz = Sys.timezone())
wrong$opening_time <- format(as.POSIXct(wrong$dt_start), format = "%H:%M")
wrong$dt_start <- as.Date(wrong$dt_start)
wrong <- wrong[, c(1, 2, 5, 3, 4)]

wrong$dt_end <- as.POSIXct(wrong$dt_end, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M", tz = Sys.timezone())
wrong$closing_time <- format(as.POSIXct(wrong$dt_end), format = "%H:%M")
wrong$dt_end <- as.Date(wrong$dt_end)
wrong <- wrong[, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5)]
wrong$weekday <- weekdays(wrong$dt_start)
```

I've changed the `weekday_code` with `weekday` in order to join the `dfs`.

```
new <- c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday")
store$weekday <- new[match(store$weekday, store$weekday_code, nomatch = 0)]
store$weekday_code <- NULL
store <- store[, c(4, 1, 2, 3)]
```

Then you can `left_join` the data frames to get the desired result.

```
library(dplyr)
wrong2 <- wrong %>%
  left_join(store, by = c("weekday")) %>%
  mutate(opening_time = coalesce(opening_time.y, opening_time.x)) %>%
  mutate(closing_time = coalesce(closing_time.y, closing_time.x)) %>%
  select(-opening_time.x, -closing_time.x, -closing_time.y, -opening_time.y)
```

The output will look like this:

```
   kod_dolg   dt_start     dt_end person_number   weekday workday_sign
1  50000690 2022-02-14 2022-02-14        976291    Monday            1
2       801 2022-02-14 2022-02-14        754105    Monday            1
3  50000690 2022-02-14 2022-02-14        867801    Monday            1
4       801 2022-02-15 2022-02-15            NA   Tuesday            1
5  50000690 2022-02-15 2022-02-15        867801   Tuesday            1
6       801 2022-02-15 2022-02-15            NA   Tuesday            1
7       801 2022-02-15 2022-02-15            NA   Tuesday            1
8  50000690 2022-02-15 2022-02-15        867801   Tuesday            1
9       801 2022-02-16 2022-02-16            NA Wednesday            1
10 50000690 2022-02-16 2022-02-16        976291 Wednesday            1
11 50000690 2022-02-16 2022-02-16        938541 Wednesday            1
12      801 2022-02-17 2022-02-17            NA  Thursday            1
13 50000690 2022-02-17 2022-02-17            NA  Thursday            1
14 50000690 2022-02-17 2022-02-17            NA  Thursday            1
15 50000690 2022-02-17 2022-02-17            NA  Thursday            1
16      801 2022-02-18 2022-02-18            NA    Friday            1
17 50000690 2022-02-18 2022-02-18            NA    Friday            1
18      801 2022-02-18 2022-02-18            NA    Friday            1
19 50000690 2022-02-18 2022-02-18            NA    Friday            1
20      801 2022-02-18 2022-02-18            NA    Friday            1
21 50000690 2022-02-18 2022-02-18            NA    Friday            1
22      801 2022-02-12 2022-02-12            NA  Saturday            1
23 50000690 2022-02-12 2022-02-12            NA  Saturday            1
24 50000690 2022-02-12 2022-02-12            NA  Saturday            1
25      801 2022-02-12 2022-02-12            NA  Saturday            1
26      801 2022-02-19 2022-02-19            NA  Saturday            1
27 50000690 2022-02-19 2022-02-19            NA  Saturday            1
28 50000690 2022-02-19 2022-02-19            NA  Saturday            1
29 50000690 2022-02-19 2022-02-19            NA  Saturday            1
30      801 2022-02-20 2022-02-20            NA    Sunday            1
31 50000690 2022-02-20 2022-02-20            NA    Sunday            1
32 50000690 2022-02-20 2022-02-20            NA    Sunday            1
33 50000690 2022-02-20 2022-02-20            NA    Sunday            1
34      801 2022-02-13 2022-02-13            NA    Sunday            1
35 50000690 2022-02-13 2022-02-13            NA    Sunday            1
36      801 2022-02-13 2022-02-13            NA    Sunday            1
37 50000690 2022-02-13 2022-02-13            NA    Sunday            1
   opening_time closing_time
1       9:00:00     18:00:00
2       9:00:00     18:00:00
3       9:00:00     18:00:00
4       9:00:00     18:00:00
5       9:00:00     18:00:00
6       9:00:00     18:00:00
7       9:00:00     18:00:00
8       9:00:00     18:00:00
9       9:00:00     18:00:00
10      9:00:00     18:00:00
11      9:00:00     18:00:00
12      9:00:00     18:00:00
13      9:00:00     18:00:00
14      9:00:00     18:00:00
15      9:00:00     18:00:00
16      9:00:00     18:00:00
17      9:00:00     18:00:00
18      9:00:00     18:00:00
19      9:00:00     18:00:00
20      9:00:00     18:00:00
21      9:00:00     18:00:00
22      9:00:00     17:00:00
23      9:00:00     17:00:00
24      9:00:00     17:00:00
25      9:00:00     17:00:00
26      9:00:00     17:00:00
27      9:00:00     17:00:00
28      9:00:00     17:00:00
29      9:00:00     17:00:00
30     10:00:00     16:00:00
31     10:00:00     16:00:00
32     10:00:00     16:00:00
33     10:00:00     16:00:00
34     10:00:00     16:00:00
35     10:00:00     16:00:00
36     10:00:00     16:00:00
37     10:00:00     16:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

First change the type of `dt_start` and `dt_end` to date time, then use `lubridate::wday()` to find out the weekday. Remember to change all characters to lower case, and change `wed` to `wen` to match your `store` style.

Then `left_join` it with `store` and `rename` it back to your style.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

wrong_with_weekday <- wrong %>% mutate(dt_start = as_datetime(dt_start, format = "%y.%m.%d"),
                 dt_end = as_datetime(dt_end, format = "%y.%m.%d"),
                 weekday_code = tolower(wday(dt_start, label = T)),
                 weekday_code = gsub("wed", "wen", weekday_code)) %>% 
  select(-dt_start, - dt_end)

left_join(wrong_with_weekday, store, by = "weekday_code") %>% 
  dplyr::rename("dt_start" = "opening_time",
                "dt_end" = "closing_time")
```

### Output

```
   kod_dolg person_number weekday_code workday_sign dt_start   dt_end
1  50000690        976291          thu            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
2       801        754105          thu            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
3  50000690        867801          thu            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
4       801            NA          fri            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
5  50000690        867801          fri            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
6       801            NA          fri            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
7       801            NA          fri            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
8  50000690        867801          fri            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
9       801            NA          sat            1  9:00:00 17:00:00
10 50000690        976291          sat            1  9:00:00 17:00:00
11 50000690        938541          sat            1  9:00:00 17:00:00
12      801            NA          mon            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
13 50000690            NA          mon            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
14 50000690            NA          mon            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
15 50000690            NA          mon            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
16      801            NA          tue            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
17 50000690            NA          tue            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
18      801            NA          tue            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
19 50000690            NA          tue            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
20      801            NA          tue            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
21 50000690            NA          tue            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
22      801            NA          mon            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
23 50000690            NA          mon            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
24 50000690            NA          mon            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
25      801            NA          mon            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
26      801            NA          wen            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
27 50000690            NA          wen            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
28 50000690            NA          wen            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
29 50000690            NA          wen            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
30      801            NA          thu            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
31 50000690            NA          thu            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
32 50000690            NA          thu            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
33 50000690            NA          thu            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
34      801            NA          wen            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
35 50000690            NA          wen            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
36      801            NA          wen            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
37 50000690            NA          wen            1  9:00:00 18:00:00
```